# Is for (auto& a : a) grammatically right?

Tags: c++, arrays, for-loop

For example, I defined an multidimensional array

```
array<array<array<int, 3>, 4>, 5> a;
```

And I loop it

```
for (auto& a : a) 
    for (auto& a : a)
        for (auto& a : a) 
            a = 1;
```

Is that right in grammar? I tested in VS2015. No compilation errors.

Comment: @Resurrection: It doesn't compile because there's mismatched `<` and `>` in the declaration of `a`.  After fixing that, it should compile because this is legal (for example clang accepts it).

Comment: @BenVoigt I have noticed and corrected it but it still does not compile in VS2015 with redefinition error. EDIT: Ok, nevermind, I had another variable named 'a' there. Well that was confusing!

Answer (score 18, accepted):

It's legal, and will do what you expect, but it is still a very bad idea to reuse variable names.

The C++11 ranged-for is defined as a source transformation, which puts definition of the range variable in an inner scope, and performs evaluation of the range expression outside that scope.

Section 6.5.4 says that

> The range-based for statement
>
> ```
> for ( for-range-declaration : for-range-initializer ) statement
> ```
>
> is equivalent to
>
> ```
> {
>    auto &&__range = for-range-initializer ;
>    auto __begin = begin-expr ;
>    auto __end = end-expr ;
>    for ( ; __begin != __end; ++__begin ) {
>       for-range-declaration = *__begin;
>       statement
>    }
> }
> ```

Comment: So I need several temp names, also not readable. Any better way?

Comment: It would be readable if you chose good names.  Not my fault you're too lazy to type multicharacter variable names.

Comment: Are they *completely* equivalent? Am I allowed to modify those internal variables?

Comment: @HolyBlackCat: They're reserved identifiers, so trying to use them in any way causes undefined behavior.  Only the compiler can use them safely.  Also, the next part of the Standard says "`__range`, `__begin`, and `__end` are variables deﬁned for exposition only" and then goes on to describe `begin-expr` and `end-expr`.

Comment: @user1899020 Look at this example: `for(auto& document : documents) for(auto& page: document) for(auto& char: page) char = 'X';`. Reading this you probably know what this will do.

Comment: I was pretty confused with this answer, because the OP asked about _grammatically_ correct. Then again, looks like you may have picked up on the real question.

Comment: @sehe: This is C++, where syntax and semantics are inseparable

Comment: That's talking like an MSVC compiler :)

Comment: @sehe: Are you referring to the lack of two-phase template analysis?  But even in a fully compliant compiler the parse, conducted in the first phase, still intermingles syntax and semantics.  (The second phase is only name lookup and overload resolution)

Comment: I am aware of these. Still, "inseparable" is a bit dramatic. I did read the question as is and was slightly confused as I thought ranged-for was pretty well known by now :)

Answer (score 6):

Yes, it is :)

The reason why is because the `a` you declare in the for loop hides the original array `a`:

```
for (auto& a : a)
          ^^^   ^^^^^^^^^
          hides   this 'a' (the original array)
```

And then, it's just the same all over again.